# How i update javafx label with downloading

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a download manager.I can not update label. I am trying to update label with downloading in `run()` method but exception occurred. How I update Label.Where I write code of updating label and ProgressBar.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class DownloadFile implements Runnable
{   
Thread thread;
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE=1024;
public final int DOWNLOADING=0;
public final int PAUSED=1;
public final int COMPLETE=2;
public final int CANCELLED=3;
public final int ERROR=4;
private URL url;
private int size;
private int downloaded;
private int status;
static int check=0;
Stage dStage;
Label fileNameLabel;
Label fileNameValueLabel; 
Label statusLabel; 
Label statusValueLabel; 
Label fileSizeLabel; 
Label fileSizeValueLabel; 
Label downloadedLabel; 
Label downloadedValueLabel; 
Label speedLabel;   
Label speedValueLabel; 
Label timeRemainingLabel; 
Label timeRemainingValueLabel;
ProgressBar downloadingProgressBar;
public void startStage()
{
    dStage=new Stage();
    dStage.setResizable(false);
    dStage.getIcons().add(new Image("images\\webdownloadmanager.png"));
    dStage.setTitle("Friends Download Manager");
    BorderPane root=new BorderPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    Scene dScene=new Scene(root,520,250);
    dStage.setScene(dScene);
    Label titleLabel=new Label("  Download Status   ");
    titleLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FFFFFF;");
    GridPane gpCenter=new GridPane();
    gpCenter.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    gpCenter.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FFFFFF;");
    fileNameLabel =new Label("File Name");
    fileNameValueLabel=new Label();
    statusLabel =new Label("Status");
    statusValueLabel =new Label();
    fileSizeLabel =new Label("File size");
    fileSizeValueLabel =new Label();
    downloadedLabel =new Label("Downloaded");
    downloadedValueLabel =new Label();
    speedLabel =new Label("Speed");
    speedValueLabel =new Label();
    timeRemainingLabel =new Label("Time Remaining    ");
    timeRemainingValueLabel =new Label();
    gpCenter.add(fileNameLabel,0,0);
    gpCenter.add(fileNameValueLabel,2,0);
    gpCenter.add(statusLabel ,0,3);
    gpCenter.add(statusValueLabel ,2,3);
    gpCenter.add(fileSizeLabel ,0,4);
    gpCenter.add(fileSizeValueLabel ,2,4);
    gpCenter.add(downloadedLabel ,0,5);
    gpCenter.add(downloadedValueLabel ,2,5);
    gpCenter.add(speedLabel ,0,6);
    gpCenter.add(speedValueLabel ,2,6);
    gpCenter.add(timeRemainingLabel ,0,7);
    gpCenter.add(timeRemainingValueLabel ,2,7);
    AnchorPane anchorPaneBottom=new AnchorPane();
    VBox vb=new VBox();
    HBox progressBarHB=new HBox();
    progressBarHB.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 30, 0));
    downloadingProgressBar=new ProgressBar();
    downloadingProgressBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().subtract(20));
    progressBarHB.getChildren().add(downloadingProgressBar);
    vb.getChildren().addAll(progressBarHB); 
    HBox labelHB=new HBox();
    Label message=new Label("Whould you like to perform ?");
    labelHB.getChildren().add(message);
    HBox buttonHB=new HBox();
    buttonHB.setSpacing(20);
    Button startPauseButton=new Button("Start");
    startPauseButton.setPrefWidth(80);
    Button cancelButton=new Button("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setPrefWidth(80);
    buttonHB.getChildren().addAll(startPauseButton,cancelButton);
    anchorPaneBottom.getChildren().addAll(vb,labelHB,buttonHB);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(buttonHB, 40.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(buttonHB,30.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(labelHB,40.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(labelHB,40.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(vb, 0.0);
    root.setTop(titleLabel);
    root.setCenter(gpCenter);
    root.setBottom(anchorPaneBottom);
    dStage.show();
    dStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
    {  
        public void handle(WindowEvent we)
        {   /*
            if(WebDownloadManager.check==0)
                Platform.exit();
            else
                check--;
            */
        }
    });     
}   
public DownloadFile(URL url)
{
    this.url=url;
    size=-1;
    downloaded=0;
    status=DOWNLOADING;
    startStage();
    fileNameValueLabel.setText(getFileName(url).toString());
    statusValueLabel.setText("Waiting..");
    fileSizeValueLabel.setText(getSize()+"");
    downloadedValueLabel.setText("0.00 MB ("+getProgress()+" %)");
    speedValueLabel.setText("450.123 KB/sec");
    timeRemainingValueLabel.setText("1 hr ");
    download(); 
}
public String getUrl()
{
    return url.toString();
}
public int getSize()
{
    return size;
}
public float getProgress()
{
    float tf=(downloaded/size)*100;
    return tf;

}
public int getStatus()
{
    return status;
}
public void pause()
{
    status=PAUSED;
}
public void resume()
{
    status=DOWNLOADING;
    download();
}
public void cancel()
{
    status=CANCELLED;
}
private void error()
{
    status=ERROR;
}
private void download()
{
    thread=new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
private String getFileName(URL url)
{
    String fileName=url.getFile();
    String str=fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1).replace("%20"," ");
    return str;
}
public void run()
{

    RandomAccessFile file=null;
    InputStream stream=null;
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Range","bytes="+downloaded+"-");
        conn.connect();
        if(conn.getResponseCode()/100!=2)
        {
            error();
        }
        int contentLength=conn.getContentLength();
        if(contentLength<1)
        {
            error();
        }
        if(size==-1)
        {
            size=contentLength;
        }

        file=new RandomAccessFile(getFileName(url),"rw");
        file.seek(downloaded);
        stream=conn.getInputStream();
        while(status==DOWNLOADING)
        {
            statusValueLabel.setText("Running..");
            byte buffer[];
            if(size-downloaded>BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                buffer=new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            else
            {
                buffer=new byte[size-downloaded];
            }
            int read=stream.read(buffer);
            if(read== -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            file.write(buffer,0,read);
            downloaded+=read;

        }
        if(status==DOWNLOADING)
        {
            status=COMPLETE;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        error();
        System.out.println("Error :"+exp);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(file!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                file.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        if(stream!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hint 1 : Read about [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and use it instead of `Runnable`.

Comment: Your question is quite hard to answer as it is. Can you 1. Simplify the code. There is way more code here than pertains to your problem. Create a simple example with just a label and how you are managing the download, and get rid of all the extra stuff. 2. Post the stack trace from the exception, and identify which line it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update JavaFX element outside FX threads. what you need to do is :

```
  Platform.runLater(new Runnable(updateMethod());
```